# No output is being returned by Objective-C Program

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am doing the project euler these days nd am now doing problem 4. In the question, I create the following code to output an result. The program runs and finishes running superfast but doesnt at all return an answer. I am confused as to why this is happening. Please help. Heres the code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

@autoreleasepool {
    int num1, num2, n , num ,reverse=0, digit;

    for (num1 = 999;num1 > 100;--num1)
    {
        for(num2 = 999;num2 > 100;--num2)
        {
            num = num1 * num2;
            n = num;
            while (num > 0)
            {
                digit = num % 10;
                reverse = reverse * 10 + digit;
                num = num / 10;
            }
            if (n == reverse)
            {
                NSLog (@"%i * %i = %i",num1,num2,n);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
return 0;
}
```

here is a link to an img, http://tinypic.com/r/347bkat/8

Comment: Check the conditions on the for loops.

Comment: Can't work, because you're not initialising "reverse". This should have given you a compiler warning.

Comment: Still not working after checking the loop errors

Comment: I tried that @gnasher729, but that didnt help either

Comment: What about now, any errors now, guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `num1 < 100` to `num1 > 100` (and the same for `num2`) in your for-loops
or they will never be executed :-)

Comment: @user3486277: You have to set `reverse=0` *each time* that you want to compute the "mirrored number", i.e. directly before `while (num > 0)`.

Comment: The initiaization of reverse doesnt seem to help, @MartinR

Comment: @user3486277:  You must set reverse = 0 BEFORE the while-loop BUT NOT **INSIDE** THE WHILE LOOP !!!!

Comment: @user3486277: I do not want to sound unfriendly, but judging from this and your previous question I really recommend to learn how to use a **debugger**.

Comment: I am so sorry is this wastes your time but thanks,and yeah I have just started programming so pls be kind and I'm sure trying to learn to use a debugger.